# Query to Yii CDbCriteria

Tags: php, yii

I need to create a query using CDbCriteria:

```
select t_devices.* 
from t_departmens, t_branches, t_cabinets, t_employees, t_devices
where t_branches.id_organization = 1
and t_departmens.id_branch = t_branches.id_branch
and t_cabinets.id_department = t_departmens.id_department
and t_employees.id_cabinet = t_cabinets.id_cabinet
and t_devices.id_employee = t_employees.id_employee
```

Comment: What have you tried? It's simple rewrite to `CDbCriteria`. Consider using relations!

Comment: Try using JOINs, they are good and helpful. After that try to create some relation, they are good too, and then use **CDbCriteria**, its also good.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select('t_devices.*'); 
$criteria->from('t_departmens, t_branches, t_cabinets, t_employees, t_devices');
$criteria->condition('t_branches.id_organization = 1
and t_departmens.id_branch = t_branches.id_branch
and t_cabinets.id_department = t_departmens.id_department
and t_employees.id_cabinet = t_cabinets.id_cabinet
and t_devices.id_employee = t_employees.id_employee
');
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to make use of Active Record (AR) relation in your model file.

Read: [Yii's active record guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)

AR relations will be generated automatically using Gii

Read: [Yii's Gii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii)